# Invalid write when trying to add a value in the cell of the matrix

Tags: c, pointers, matrix

I'm trying to add values inside a matrix.
For the first row everyting goes well.
However, when I'm trying to access the second row (if there's one), I get an invalid write.

Here is the the different version I wrote :

1. mat[i][j]
2. *(*(mat + i) + j)
3. mat[i * N + j]

```c
int** matrice(int N, int M){
    int **mat = (int **)malloc(N * sizeof(int*));
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) mat[i] = (int *)malloc(M * sizeof(int));

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        for (int j = 0; i < M; j++){
            //mat[i][j] = i+j;
        }
    }

    return mat;
}
```

Comment: Also be careful, `malloc` doesn't initialize the memory it allocates, the data you won't explicitly initialize will contain *indeterminate* (seemingly random or garbage) values.

Comment: And in C you [don't need to cast the result of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: voting to close as a simple typo : `i < M` instead of `j < M`

Comment: Related: [Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays)

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your nested `for` loop that uses `j` as index, however, you compare with `i`:

```
for (int j = 0; i < M; j++)
```

should be

```
for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
```